# How to identify dependency file location for a dependency in a build plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to write a custom maven plugin. Part of what the plugin will do is examine the JAR files in the m2 folder of other dependencies listed along side it in a `<plugin>` tag. I will need the exact JAR file/location.

Example:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>myPluginGroup</groupId>
                <artifactId>myPluginArtifact</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <!-- find me -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
....
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

So i want to be able to scan and find "example.example" and point it to "C:\User\username\.m2\repository\example\example\1.0.0\example-1.0.0.jar".

I can find the plugin dependencies with:

```
final List<Plugin> plugins = project.getBuild().getPlugins();

for (Plugin plugin : plugins) {
    final List<Dependency> dependencyArtifacts = plugin.getDependencies();
    for (Dependency dependency : dependencyArtifacts) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This doesn't give me the location of the JARs, but it does provide the list of build plugin dependencies which is part of what I need.

I can get some locations with:

```
DependencyNode rootNode = treeBuilder.buildDependencyTree(project, localRepository,
    artifactFactory, artifactMetadataSource, artifactFilter, artifactCollector);

CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor();

rootNode.accept(visitor);

List<DependencyNode> nodes = visitor.getNodes();
for (DependencyNode dependencyNode : nodes) {
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't provide plugins and even for what it does provide, it doesn't provide all m2 locations.

Is there a way to identify dependency file locations for dependencies in a build plugin?

Comment: What for do you want to scan plugin dependencies? Plugin dependencies are on plugin classpath so you can use eg `class.getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski What I want to do is almost akin of a custom compiler. I want to pull in the JARs of the dependencies listed and do my process on them. I want to scan the source JARs if they are downloaded, and there is no preplanned resource to pull in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven Resolver Api to resolve artifacts, in your case code can look like:

(example without loops - only final usage of resolver)

```java
public class MyMojo {

    @Component
    private RepositorySystem repoSystem;

    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${repositorySystemSession}", readonly = true )
    private RepositorySystemSession repoSession;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true)
    protected MavenProject project;

    void resolveOneArtifact() throws ArtifactResolutionException {
        Dependency dependency = project.getBuild().getPlugins().get(0).getDependencies().get(0);

        ArtifactRequest request = new ArtifactRequest();
        request.setArtifact(RepositoryUtils.toDependency(dependency, repoSession.getArtifactTypeRegistry()).getArtifact());
        request.setRepositories(project.getRemotePluginRepositories());

        ArtifactResult artifactResult = repoSystem.resolveArtifact(repoSession, request);
        System.out.println(artifactResult.getArtifact().getFile());
    }

    void resolveArtifactWithTransitiveDependencies() throws DependencyResolutionException {
        Dependency dependency = project.getBuild().getPlugins().get(0).getDependencies().get(0);

        CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
        collectRequest.setRoot(RepositoryUtils.toDependency(dependency, repoSession.getArtifactTypeRegistry()));
        collectRequest.setRepositories(project.getRemotePluginRepositories());

        DependencyRequest request = new DependencyRequest();
        request.setCollectRequest(collectRequest);

        DependencyResult dependencyResult = repoSystem.resolveDependencies(repoSession, request);
        ArtifactResult artifactResult = dependencyResult.getArtifactResults().get(0);

        System.out.println(artifactResult.getArtifact().getFile());
    }
}
```

More examples please investigate code: https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/tree/master/maven-resolver-demos